# How to reconstruct the result of ColorBalance manually?

Tags: image-processing, color, implementation-details

I want to know about the mathematics behind white balance. I understand that it should be 3 different constants being applied to the red/green/blue channels. Thus I used `img1` as the original image and `img2` as the balanced image (used `RGBColor[.1, 0.4, 0.5]` as the white color and picked line `100` as the sample line to allow faster calculation):-

```
img1 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl"}]
img2 = ColorBalance[img1, RGBColor[.1, 0.4, 0.5]]

line = 100;
data1 = (ImageData@img1)[[line, All]];
data2 = (ImageData@img2)[[line, All]];

data3 = data2/data1;
Mean@data3
```

In fact, `data3` fluctuated around `{1.4, 0.8, 0.6}` and `{1.2, 0.7, 0.5}`. I took the average and then `Mean@data3` gives me `{1.35116, 0.828725, 0.591499}` as the output.

My question is, how does this `{1.35116, 0.828725, 0.591499}` related to `RGBColor[.1, 0.4, 0.5]` mathematically? I just want a rough formulae and an approximation with error is good enough. I tested different `RGBColor` color (I focused on the RGB values which give a sum of `1`), but still can't find the relationship between the two. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance) gives a formula, but I don't think that is applicable to this case.

Many thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation of `ColorBalance`: "With a given {temperature, tint} pair, ... [not your case]. Otherwise, Method->"LMSScaling" is used". And that scales in the LMS color space. For the equations, see the Wikipedia article you linked.

Comment: Thanks. I got a closed approximation by `img2 = ColorBalance[img1, RGBColor[.3, 0.4, 0.5], Method -> "RGBScaling"]`, and then reciprocal.